# How to select element in nav

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
<!-- /.navbar-top-links -->

        <div class='navbar-default sidebar' role='navigation'>
            <div class='sidebar-nav navbar-collapse'>
                <ul class='nav' id='side-menu'>
                    <li class='sidebar-search'>
                        <div class='input-group custom-search-form'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search...'>
                            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                            <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'>
                                <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=''>
                        <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw'></i> Pages<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>
                        <ul class='nav nav-second-level collapse' aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'>
                    <li><a href="/seattle.php">Seattle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new-york.php">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/london.php">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
```

I am trying to select the drop down links like Seattle or London with this jQuery `$("").click(function(e)` but I cannot.

please help

Comment: have you tried this [`$("a[href='/seattle.php']")`](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

Answer (score 0):

Target the second level nav:

```
$('.nav-second-level li').on('click', 'a', function(){
       //do your thing here
      var text = $(this).text();
      alert(text );
 });
```

```js
$('.nav-second-level li').on('click', 'a', function() {
  //do your thing here
  var text = $(this).text();
  alert(text);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='navbar-default sidebar' role='navigation'>
  <div class='sidebar-nav navbar-collapse'>
    <ul class='nav' id='side-menu'>
      <li class='sidebar-search'>
        <div class='input-group custom-search-form'>
          <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search...'>
          <span class='input-group-btn'>
                            <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'>
                                <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
        </div>
        <!-- /input-group -->
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> Home</a>
      </li>
      <li class=''>
        <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw'></i> Pages<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>
        <ul class='nav nav-second-level collapse' aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'>
          <li><a href="#">Seattle</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">New York</a>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">London</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
</div>
<!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply giv the `ul` an id and catch it:

```
<ul class='nav nav-second-level collapse' id="nested_list" aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'>
                    <li><a href="/seattle.php">Seattle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new-york.php">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/london.php">London</a></li>
                        </ul>

$("#nested_list li a").click(function(e){

});
```

Or going through the tree simple CSS:

```
$("#side-menu li ul li a").click(function(e){

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the element by adding and removing the active class

```
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```js
$(".nav a").on("click", function(){
   $(".nav").find(".active").removeClass("active");
   $(this).parent().addClass("active");
});
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- /.navbar-top-links -->
<nav>
        <div class='navbar-default sidebar' role='navigation'>
            <div class='sidebar-nav navbar-collapse'>
                <ul class='nav' id='side-menu'>
                    <li class='sidebar-search'>
                        <div class='input-group custom-search-form'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search...'>
                            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                            <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'>
                                <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='#'><i class='active fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=''>
                        <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw'></i> Pages<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>
                        <ul class='nav nav-second-level collapse' aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'>
                    <li><a href="/seattle.php">Seattle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new-york.php">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/london.php">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
        <!-- /.navbar-static-side -->
    </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since those are anchor tags `<a>`, when you click on one of those whatever you have in jQuery will be ignored and you will redirected to the link in 'href'.

If you want something else to happen, then you have the prevent the default behavior using preventDefault()

```
$("a").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var link = $(this).attr('href');
    //do something
    document.location.href = link;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Do it with https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/

```js
$("a[href='/seattle.php']").on('click',function (E) { $(this).text('Changed!');E.preventDefault();return false;});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='navbar-default sidebar' role='navigation'>
            <div class='sidebar-nav navbar-collapse'>
                <ul class='nav' id='side-menu'>
                    <li class='sidebar-search'>
                        <div class='input-group custom-search-form'>
                            <input type='text' class='form-control' placeholder='Search...'>
                            <span class='input-group-btn'>
                            <button class='btn btn-default' type='button'>
                                <i class='fa fa-search'></i>
                            </button>
                        </span>
                        </div>
                        <!-- /input-group -->
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href='index.php'><i class='fa fa-dashboard fa-fw'></i> Home</a>
                    </li>
                    <li class=''>
                        <a href='#'><i class='fa fa-bar-chart-o fa-fw'></i> Pages<span class='fa arrow'></span></a>
                        <ul class='nav nav-second-level collapse' aria-expanded='false' style='height: 0px;'>
                    <li><a href="/seattle.php">Seattle</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/new-york.php">New York</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/london.php">London</a></li>
                        </ul>
                        <!-- /.nav-second-level -->
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- /.sidebar-collapse -->
        </div>
```